# Drush command l10n_update could not be found, but is present in Drupal site

Tags: drush

Installed Drush 6.6.0 using composer following instructions on drush.org. Works fine. I have a set of site aliases in ~/.drush/mysite.aliases.drushrc.php: mysite.dev, mysite.stage, mysite.prod

All the aliases work fine and I can do all built-in commands like `drush @mysite.dev up` etc.

However, modules that are present in `@mysite.dev/sites/all/modules/contrib` that support Drush are not found. E.g. l10n_update.

I can do commands like `drush @mysite.dev up l10n_update` which works fine. I can use the module through the web interface and it works fine. 
But I cannot do `drush @mysite.dev l10n_update`. 
It throws the error `The drush command 'l10n_update' could not be found.  Run 'drush cache-clear drush' to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.`
Even when the current dir is anywhere in `@mysite.dev` or `@mysite.dev/all/modules/contrib/l10n_update/`

I've tried `drush cc drush` and `drush cc all` multiple times in various locations in and outside of the site root without success.

I've read numerous similar questions on this site and followed all suggestions (when relevant to my Drush version), but nothing helps.

I know I had it working long time ago pre composer, but I cannot find what to do now.

**Update** the correct command is `l10n-update` not `l10n_update`. Only looked over it a million times. :-(

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Do you mean you keep trying the wrong command?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Basically, yes. I typed it in once and switched directories but arrowed up to the command because I was too lazy to type it in again. It was only after I copied from the readme file to apply it to \@mysite.prod that I noticed my typo.